# Why are minterms so important?

Tags: digital-logic

So this might be a hilarious question for some, but I think this is where my gap in understanding of digital logic design lies. **I know the parts before simplification of minterms and so on. And now I am studying decoders, multiplexers and so on. In the middle I feel I have missed something.** Decoders, for example, output the possible minterms. K maps use minterms. Why?

Comment: They help you reduce a logic function to a standard form that can implemented with the smallest number of transistors or gates.

Comment: @mkeith. If that is an answer, you should post it as an answer so we can vote on it and close it out.

Comment: @Sparky256, if you think it is sufficient to answer the question, you can paste it into an answer with my blessing. I think it is maybe a bit too brief.

Answer (score 1):

The underlying goal of using minterms is to simplify the logic used to reach a defined output. This includes component logic as well as complex FPGA's. By 'simplify' the logic I mean that there could be at least 3 possible goals. 
One is to have the minimum number of gates as part of a logic or numeric operation, another is to insure a fixed time delay to avoid metastable states, such as gating a clock signal, and another use is to prevent race conditions where a logic tree must be completed before another chain of logic runs.
 In other words (simple example); output C needs input B to have the results of thread A completed or C is not valid. Minterms and maxterms branch out into integrals and other logical deductions such as AB!C = 110 base2 = 6 'base 10'. For more detail that covers more than I can write in a day, [I found this article in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_normal_form).

Answer (score -1):

I'm not totally clear about your question: either you want to know why we use minterms in boolean equations or why we usually use minterms instead of maxterms. So I'll try to answer both.

By using minterms in boolean equations you can:

- easily know how the input of AND gates and OR gates (or input of NAND and NOR gate) are connected.  If I give you a complex truth table with more input, how could you decide how the AND gates and OR gates will be connected.
- In the advance case, you can design your whole Boolean equation as one logic chip in CMOS using the minimum number of MOSFET
- When you want to design a FPGA or something like that, without minterms how could you decide the connections?

And if you think, why do we use minterms instead of maxterms, I say it's not necessary for you use minterms. Generally it became a practice. But it's easy to calculate minterms for an equation then maxterms (try to solve some Boolean equation minimization with both minterms and maxterms, you will see).  That's why we go for minterms instead of maxterms.

Same goes for K map. there is a way to solve boolean equation using maxterms but we just used to do with minterms. you can take any of the paths.

Comment: Mainly the reason one seems easier than the other is that we are mentally biased by high school algebra. "." being distributive over "+" feels natural while "+" being distributed over "." feels alien and strange.

Answer (score -1):

Digital systems are implicitly binary. Barring unpredictable race conditions, the output(s) of a digital circuit (1 or 0) is a function of its inputs at that instant, or also dependent on previous inputs, if its a sequential circuit. If the output isn't a 1, then its a 0. So, if one can obtain all the possible combinations of the inputs that yield 1, one can confidently say the system has been described. This is what minterms do and why they are used; they enable us define a circuit in terms of the combination of its inputs that would result in a 1. And since they are based on the AND gate, any combination of inputs that *isn't* one of the minterms will obviously return a 0 at the output. Tools like De-Morgan's Theorem and K-maps help make minterm equations more efficient, in terms of the component count needed to realize the digital circuit in question.

Comment: I think s/he knows what is meanterms and what it does .

Comment: @Anklon You do not know what they know. They asked why minterms are used in K-maps, etc. in digital electronics, and I explained this. If I misunderstood the question, that's for the OP to say.